# Website shows differently on iPhone 5 compared to Chrome's iPhone 5 simulator

Tags: ios, css, iphone, google-chrome-devtools

My single-page webapp http://amillionmarbles.com looks fine on a desktop. In Chrome, when I simulate the iPhone 5 it looks fine.

On an actual iPhone 5s, it does not look fine.

[[image: actual iphone 5[2]]
[image: Chrome]

```
</div>
</center>
</body>
```

style.css

```
    .buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.game-display {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.button1 {
    background-image: url('logo.png');
    display: flex;
}

.button2-unselected {
    background:#34495e;
    background-image: url('redunselected.png'); 
}

.button3-unselected {
    background:#34495e;
    background-image: url('blueunselected.png');    
}

.button4-unselected {
    background:#34495e;
    background-image: url('greenunselected.png');   
}

.button2-selected {
    background:#9b59b6;
    background-image: url('red.png');   
}

.button3-selected {
    background:#9b59b6;
    background-image: url('blue.png');  
}

.button4-selected {
    background:#9b59b6;
    background-image: url('green.png'); 
}

.button-more {
    text: "More";   
}

.button-about {
    body: "About";
}

.button-donate {
    inner-html: "Donate";
}

.box {
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tip2 { background: #9b59b6; }
.retry { background: #16a085;
         display: flex;
}
.backup {
 background: #e74c3c;
display: flex; }

.tip5 { background:#3498db; }
.tip20 { background:#e57e22; }
```

Comment: That's not very surprising, Chrome's device profiles aren't a full simulator or an emulator, it's just a profile that's kind-of similar. The closest thing to a physical i-device you could get would be the iOS Simulator in Xcode.

Comment: In this case, I think your main problem is probably that Apple's WebKit does not yet support the un-prefixed flexbox specification.

Comment: "Unprefixed" ? specification? I'm googling but can you elaborate on prefixed or unpreixed?

Comment: Apparently iOS9 does finally support the flexbox spec: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. Check what version of iOS you have.

Comment: Aha! Thank you @AlexanderO'Mara -- the device I tested on is 8.4.1.

Comment: You would need vendor prefixes and/or older spec properties to support older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding meta data view port in head of your document and make the canvas width set to 100% on a device specific media queries.

**Head Of Document**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: table;
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*flex-direction: row;*/
}

.buttons { 
    display: table-cell;
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}
.game-display { 
    display: table-cell;
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}
```

Hope this resolves your iPhone 5s issue

Comment: Is that width of its container? To be clear, the canvas element must sit side by side the buttons, so it can't take up 100% of the screen width.

Comment: Meta view port will set your frameset to fit into the chromes simulator as well as the realtime in the device. Setting the canvas width to 100% will not mess your columns you used for the  buttons in side. Give it a try if that works. If not we will conisder other solution.

Comment: If you want to avoid using the flex box to make it compatible with iOS you can use table and table cells instead.

Comment: I have updated the code by removing the flex and adding with the iOS which supports as flex-box specs not supported by iOS.